# How to parse multiple files in multipart form-data with django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data

I am receiving an array with a few files. My request.data looks like this:

```
<QueryDict: {'image': [<TemporaryUploadedFile: image_1.png (image/png)>, <TemporaryUploadedFile: image_2.png (image/png)>]
```

However, if I try to parse images like this:

```
request.data['image']
```

I only can see the last image, and django rest framework recognize it as a file object, not a list.
If I try to iterate over it all I can see is bytes.

I am using a ModelViewset and added this parsers

```
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `QueryDict` has a special function to obtain *all* values associated with a specific key: [**`getlist(key)`** [doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist). So you can write it like:

```
request.data.getlist('image')  # list of images
```

You can then process every image separately (for example in a `for` loop).

Or like specified in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist):

> ```
> QueryDict.getlist(key, default=None)
> ```
>
> Returns a list of the data with the requested key. Returns an empty list if the key doesn't exist and a default value wasn’t provided. It's guaranteed to return a list unless the `default` value provided is' a list.

If you perform indexing (like `request.data[key]`), then Python will call [**`__getitem__`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.__getitem__) behind the curtains, and this will result in:

> ```
> QueryDict.__getitem__(key)
> ```
>
> Returns the value for the given key. If the key has more than one value, it returns the **last value**. Raises `django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError` if the key does not exist. (This is a subclass of Python's standard `KeyError`, so you can stick to catching `KeyError`.)